# Reusing a property value from within an object initializer

Tags: c#

First of all sorry for the intriguing title of my question, hopefuly a code sample exposing my problem will clarify things.

Below you will find a code sample that does not compile (and I totally get why, no need to explain) but which expose what I am trying to achieve:

```
public class Cmd
{
    public Byte MyByte { get; set; }
    public Byte MyOtherByte { get; set; }
    public String MyString { get; set; }

    public static Cmd FromStream(Stream stream)
    {
        return new Cmd
        {
            MyByte = (Byte)stream.ReadByte(),
            MyOtherByte = (Byte)stream.ReadByte(),
            MyString = SomeMethodBasedOnMyOtherByte(MyOtherByte) // Here
        };
    }
}
```

I hope you get the idea. Of course if the stream is seekable I could just seek back one byte and reread it for passing it as the argument of the method I am calling. But if the stream is non seekable, no way.

This is a very basic example of course, in my real scenario the classes on which I would like to implement FromStream have many different properties.

Is there any keyword that allows to do what I am trying to do, basically reusing an affected property value from within an object initializer block ?

If not I guess the only way for me would be not to use an object initializer in this context, and construct a new object affecting it's properties one by one (so that I can reuse affected properties if needed). And wouldn't it be nice to have (or reuse) a keyword for this specific scenario in object initializer ? If not, why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think having a temp varable will make your code more clear.

```
    Byte myByte = (Byte)stream.ReadByte();
    return new Cmd
    {
        MyByte = myByte,
        MyString = SomeMethodBasedOnMyFirstByte(myByte)
    };
```

Alternatively, you could take a `Byte` as a (private) constructor.

Comment: Thanks. However in this pretty simple sample it would work, but in my real conditions, the byte is not the first thing that is read from the stream. I have updated my code sample to expose the fact that it cannot work with a temp variable.

Comment: @darkey - I would then just initialize it in a constructor.